# Using mysql event scheduler and php

Tags: mysql, database

I would like to delete records from my database every 2 minutes.

I have a user table where I would like to delete users who are active after 2 minutes. I have read a little about using mysql event scheduler but unsure if I can achieve it?

wanted to ask if anybody has previously done anything similar who could help me start ?

Comment: You want to delete users who are _active after 2 minutes_? I'm sure that will please them.

Comment: @TheBlueDog for testing purposes, I am. In the future would keep this a weekly thing

Answer (score 2):

You Can Create An Event SCHEDULE on your Mysql Server 
First thing You must switch the event SCHEDULE to on that is because its Always off by default Run this Sql Query

```
 SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

After That You can create an Event Schedule to delete your records from the table every 2 min You can use a query like this

```
  DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS EventName
ON SCHEDULE EVERY  2 MINUTE
DO
BEGIN

DELETE FROM Your Table WHERE Your Conditions if Exists;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

This Event will automatically deletes your specific records every 2 min